# What is Mylan stockholder tax responsibility in Viatris merger?

Tags: income-tax

Can a Mylan stockholder declare a capital loss due to the merger with Viatris.  I have a $40,000.00 loss on my Mylan stock.
Also, if I sell the Viatris is the holding date when I purchased Mylan (3 02 2015) or when the Viatris merger occurred (11 16 2020)?

Answer (score 1):

Even though it was an [all-stock merger](https://www.businesswire.com/news/home/20201116005378/en/Pfizer-Completes-Transaction-to-Combine-Its-Upjohn-Business-with-Mylan), Viatris in their form 8937 says that US shareholders should declare a realized gain/loss as if they had sold their Mylan shares for $15.66.

In the future, if you sell your Viatris shares, you will have another capital gain/loss with a new basis of $15.66.

Comment: Thank you.  In the mean time I have found the 8937 filed by Viatris.  It says on line 28 that a loss can be claimed by Mylan stockholders.  Mylan was a Dutch company that merged with Viatris a US company in a triangular merger.  That and page 143 of the Schedule 14A filed by Mylan makes this very confusing.

Comment: Sorry it was line 18 of the 8937 filed by Viatris.

Comment: Thanks, Changed my answer.

Comment: Thank you.  You interpreted the 8937 the same as I did. My problem is that my broker has on my 1099B that the loss is not allowed.  When I presented the 8937 and SEC information to them they said just ignore what was on the 1099B.  I asked to have it revised or for them to put it in writing. They just run around the bush and say it doesn't matter.  The IRS told me to get it in writing, otherwise, it will throw a flag on my return and all I will have is a he said/she said, which the IRS doesn't put an